# Not able to fetch proxy details

Tags: java, spring-boot, proxy

I am working on a Springboot application and my task is to fetch proxy details of the client systems (Windows machines behind a proxy) as java code is hosted on RHEL Unix box (again behind another proxy). I am using below code snippet in Services.java to fetch proxy detail.

Flow is like (CustomSpringApplication.java -> Controller.java -> Services.java)
 When I place above code in Controller or Service layer, this code does not fetch proxy details. But it fetches proxy details only when I place this code inside main thread i.e. CustomSpringApplication.java but for some reasons, I cannot place this code there as this impact connection to database.

```
System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");

  List<Proxy> l = ProxySelector.getDefault().select(new URI("https://www.google.ca/"));             

  for (Iterator<Proxy> iter = l.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {

     Proxy proxy = iter.next();

     logger.debug("proxy type : " + proxy.type());

     InetSocketAddress addr = (InetSocketAddress) proxy.address();                 

     if (addr == null) {

        logger.debug("No Proxy");

     } else {

        logger.debug("proxy hostname : " + addr.getHostName());

        proxyMap.put(Constants.PROXY_KEY, addr.getHostName());

        logger.debug("proxy port : " + addr.getPort());

        proxyMap.put(Constants.PORT_KEY, addr.getPort()+"");

     }

  }
```

Please help me how can I fetch proxy detail in my Springboot application.

Edit 1: I got to know that we cannot fetch proxy details if our code runs on server. So I wrote down my code in javascript which runs on client end and there I was able to hit the required website (which was the actual ask). Thanks. This question can be closed.

The code I used in java script is as below: This does not require proxy.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
tmpUrl = proxyurl + url;
xhr.open(method, tmpUrl);
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you pasted above for finding out the proxy will always fetch proxy info of the machine where code is running/deployed. As you said your original ask was something else for which you run the code on UI layer that seems right approach. Good Luck but take care of CORS issue there.